# How are Pauling's rules applied to Nitric acid?

Tags: acid-base

The Lewis structure of nitric acid is:

[image]

So, since Pauling's rule is $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=8-5p$, where $p$ is the number of oxo groups, how is the rule applied in this instance? $p=1.5$? $p=2$?

Comment: Have you tried looking at its $\mathrm{pK_a}$? What about comparing it with the $\mathrm{pK_a}$ of its less oxygenated congener nitrous acid, $\ce{HNO2}$?

Comment: Both oxygens count as oxo - it doesn't matter how they are bonded but that they stabilise charge of anion counts.